# Angular Recorder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, commonjs

In Angular 8, I want to convert audio captured through browser to ogg format. For that, I'm using opus-recorder library: https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder

I did `npm install opus-recorder`

```
  const opusRecorder = require('opus-recorder');

  startRecording() {

    var options = {
      encoderPath: './assets/encoderWorker.min.js'
    };

    let recorder = new opusRecorder.Recorder(options);

    recorder.start().catch(function(e) {
      console.log('Error encountered:', e.message );
    });
  }
```

The github repository says that `The Recorder object is available in the global namespace and supports CommonJS and AMD imports.`

I get the following error when I call startRecording():

> ERROR TypeError: opusRecorder.Recorder is not a constructor

Am I using the library correctly? Am I importing it correctly? Can it be used in Angular?

Comment: Try it like this:  let recorder = new opusRecorder.Recorder( [options] );

Comment: @Koga Hi, I solved it by doing `import * as opusRecorder from 'opus-recorder';` and then `let recorder = new opusRecorder1(options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing `import * as opusRecorder from 'opus-recorder';` and then `let recorder = new opusRecorder1(options);`